# Table-Value Function, Set Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on the Table-Valued function and I need some help. Here is what I got, but it looks like that Table-value function doesn't like to declare any variable inside the RETURN() statement.

As you can see that I am capturing the columns name (using Declare/Set variables), but it doesn't seem to work value table-valued.

Please advise another method. If possible, please provide some sample codes.

Thank you,

```
Alter FUNCTION getCompanySaleYears()
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    -- //////// START: Get the Years and put them in the String for columns /////////
    Declare @StartYear INT, @EndYear INT, @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
    Declare @StrYears varchar(max);
    Set @StartYear = 2011;
    SET @EndYear = Year(Getdate());

    SET @StrYears = ''

    WHILE @StartYear <= @EndYear
    BEGIN
        SET @StrYears = @StrYears + ', [' + cast(@StartYear as varchar(10)) + ']'
        SET @StartYear = @StartYear + 1 
    END

    Select @StrYears = (SUBSTRING(@StrYears, 2, LEN(@StrYears)) )
    -- //////// START: Get the Years and put them in the String for columns /////////


    SET @sql = N'
    SELECT CompanyID, ' + @StrYears + '
    FROM (
        SELECT CompanyID, SalesYear, SUM(TotalSO) AS TotalSO FROM (
            SELECT c.CompanyID, o.OrderID, YEAR(o.CreatedDate) AS SalesYear
            , ISNULL((Select SUM(ExtQty * UnitSell) FROM dbo.OrderDetail WHERE OrderID = o.OrderID  ), 0) AS TotalSO
            FROM dbo.Company c
            LEFT JOIN Order o ON o.CompanyID = c.CompanyID
            WHERE 1 = 1
            --AND c.CompanyID = o2.CompanyID
            AND YEAR(o.CreatedDate) BETWEEN ''2011'' And Year(Getdate())

        ) z
        GROUP BY CompanyID, SalesYear
    ) x
    PIVOT
    (
        Sum(TotalSO)
        FOR SalesYear
        IN (
            ' + @StrYears + ' 
        )   
    ) AS pvtSalesYear
    '

    PRINT @sql
    EXEC (@sql)
)
```

Comment: FYI: You cannot use Dynamic SQL inside a SQL function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this cannot be done using a TVF as SQL expects are hard returned schema, not a flexible one as you have made.

You can have variables in a TVF, you just need the other syntax

```
ALTER FUNCTION ...() RETURNS @t TABLE(CompanyID int, ...) AS BEGIN
  INSERT @t(CompanyID,...) SELECT companyid,... FROM dbo.Company c LEFT JOIN...
  RETURN;
END;
```

Comment: I am basically want to capture the years dynamically, then add those columns for the select and pivot statement. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: A hack-around I've used for the annoying fixed schemaness of SQL's TVFs is I return an XML column and you can easily extract from that. Another technique is to hard-code a fixed number of columns, say 10, labeled A-J that get the TotalSO in them for each year.

Comment: or you can have it return a string and have the caller EXEC that (super hackey)

Comment: although I could not figure out how to make it works as you suggested, thank you for responding.